# Hello everyone, in phpexcel with floating point

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

in phpexcel problem with floating point, I'm from Russia, we decided to share bits of places, to do so would have been a comma or a point depending on the country 99,667 or 99.667

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(
                        $i + 1,
                        $key + 5,
                        '=COUNTIF(' . PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(
                            $i - $cntDate
                        ) . ($key + 5) . ':' . PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i - 1) . ($key + 5) . ',"<99.667")'
                    );
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question here.

Comment: @Fluffeh It is about decimal mark.

Comment: @Phantom how to use Russian in formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try wrapping the number in floatval() ?

Comment: The problem in that at us in Russia are written to excel of number of float in formulas through a comma, and returns to floatval type number *. ***